# Getting the handle of another application (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, handle

I need to get the handle of a window with a specific name from my vb.net application.  The form isn't actually from my application.

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to dig into the WIN32 API.

Take a look [here](http://www.andreavb.com/tip020001.html).